# How does networking in older P2P programs like Kazaa or Limewire work?

Tags: networking, file-sharing, p2p

I'm specifically interested in how a node queries the other nodes for search results.

I originally thought that the node would send a multicast message to all other nodes on the network. But besides being a large strain on the network, that can't be the case because every router between all nodes on the network would need to be configured to use multicast, which, at best, would provide an incredibly poor user experience.

The only other way I can think of is for there to be a central server that keeps track of every node. Nodes would join the network by sending a list of their files to the central server. All queries would actually be nodes querying that central server.

Although the subsequent file sharing follows a P2P model, querying the network seems to me like more of a client/server model.

Is this what actually happens? If not, what is actually going on when a node queries the network?

Comment: The same way Napster worked.  That is an actual serious answer.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm afraid of your answer, but... How does the networking in Napster work?

Comment: How Napster worked is actually well documented.  Which is the reason I indicated, that as my answer, to give you a push in the right direction in your research

Comment: Okay, I looked up how Napster worked, and it does indeed use a central server that keeps track of connected nodes and their list of files. Interestingly Gnutella only keeps track of connected nodes (no file list). The search is done by constructing an overlay network and flooding that network.